# SSIS job failed to connect to database

Tags: sql-server, ssis

After successfully deploying my SSIS package, the job in SQL Server was failed.
Apparently this is something to do with SSIS data flows connecting to my database but I can't figure what's wrong.
The error code from the log file is below.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

```
Error: 2012-09-28 05:21:59.59     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: FG2_Upload Connection manager "haisql014\haisql014<c/>3184.TLGS.tlgsAdmin"     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  
An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.  An OLE DB record is available.
Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user 'tlgsAdmin'.".  End Error  
Error: 2012-09-28 05:21:59.60     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: Data Flow Task FG20 IVB OLE DB Destination [24]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  
The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "haisql014\haisql014<c/>3184.TLGS.tlgsAdmin" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  
There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  End Error  
Error: 2012-09-28 05:21:59.60     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Data Flow Task FG20 IVB SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "OLE DB Destination" (24) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.  End Error  
Error: 2012-09-28 05:21:59.60     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Data Flow Task FG20 IVB SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  
Error: 2012-09-28 05:21:59.60     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Data Flow Task FG20 IVB      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  
Started:  5:21:56 AM  Finished: 5:21:59 AM  Elapsed:  3.276 seconds.  
The package execution failed.  The step failed.,00:00:03,0,0,,,,0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the following answer, it details how to troubleshoot these type of issues when a package it's failing running on a Sql job.

[troubleshooting sql jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12555397/920359)